# characters and files in C++

Tags: c++

I have to make a program where the filename is composed of two parts: the first one is fixed and the second one can change during the program e.g "fixpart_integer.dat". I tried to do this in C++ but I did not succeed. The fisrt probelm is: how can i convert a number to a char ; and how can i concanate these 2 characters ; and how to declare this final char in the right way in order to open this filename ?

Many questions but I did find an easy way to do this.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?  Also, is this a homework assignment?  If so, use the homework tag.

Comment: You may want to begin with a good book on C++. It takes a certain base level of knowledge before a programming forum like StackOverflow becomes the right tool to solve your problems. Take a look at your local bookstore or a web tutorial.

Comment: Your question does not make it clear that you are familiar with the concept of string in C. You can either restrict your question to C++ only and postpone the moment you will have to learn about them, or you can learn the basics about strings in C, for instance from http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html

Comment: No, it is not an homework at all.  I just have to do this program for my personal work but I don't have time to look in details to strings in C and what I red in a book was not enough to succeed.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string make_filename(std::string prefix, int id) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << prefix << "_" << id << ".dat";
  return ss.str();
}
```

and then I convert the string to char.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with c you may try the function described in here [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/)

else if you are working woth c++ you may try something like this:

```
#include <sstream>

int i = 5;
std::string s;
std::stringstream out;
out << i;
s = out.str();
```